# C++11 - is initialization of a reference not (part of) an expression?

Tags: c++, c++11

Consider

```
struct A {
   ~A() {std::cout << "A's dtor called\n";}
};

A f1(const A& a) 
{
   return a;
}

int main()
{
   {
      const A& r = f1(A());
      std::cout << "XXX\n";
   }
   std::cout << "YYY\n";
}
```

Output:

```
A's dtor called
XXX
A's dtor called
YYY
```

Now let

```
const A& f2(const A& a) 
{
   return a;
}
```

and consider the output of the same main-function except that `f1` is replaced with `f2`:

Output this time:

```
A's dtor called
XXX
YYY
```

Why is that? Shouldn't - in the second case - the temporary `A()` that is passed through `f2` "live" until the *entire* expression `const A& r = f2(A())` has been executed? In that case I'd expect that the lifetime of the temporary should be extended until `r` dies (as in the first case), but it dies already before `cout << "XXX"` gets executed. Or is the initialization of `r` not part of the expression into which the evaluation of `f2` is involved, so that `A()` is already dead before it can be bound to `r`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short, the lifetime of a temporary object is **normally** **not** extended if it **has been previously materialized** when a reference is bound to it (i.e. the materialization is not caused by this reference bounding).

In the first case, the temporary object is materialized from `f1(A())` (as @BoPersson said, this is a different temporary object from that materialized from `A()`) when `r` is bound to it, so its lifetime is the same as `r`. In the second case, when `r` is bound to the temporary object, it has been previously materialized from `A()`, so its lifetime is not extended.

Strictly speaking, consider [[class.temporary]/6](http://www.eel.is/c++draft/class.temporary#6):

> The third context is when a reference is bound to a temporary object. The temporary object to which the reference is bound or the temporary object that is the complete object of a subobject to which the reference is bound persists for the lifetime of the reference if the glvalue to which the reference is bound was obtained through one of the following:
>
> - a temporary materialization conversion ([conv.rval]),
> - ( expression ), where expression is one of these expressions,
> - subscripting ([expr.sub]) of an array operand, where that operand is one of these expressions,
> - a class member access ([expr.ref]) using the . operator where the left operand is one of these expressions and the right operand designates a non-static data member of non-reference type,
> - a pointer-to-member operation ([expr.mptr.oper]) using the .* operator where the left operand is one of these expressions and the right operand is a pointer to data member of non-reference type,
> - a
>
>   - const_­cast ([expr.const.cast]),
>   - static_­cast ([expr.static.cast]),
>   - dynamic_­cast ([expr.dynamic.cast]), or
>   - reinterpret_­cast ([expr.reinterpret.cast])
>
>   converting, without a user-defined conversion, a glvalue operand that is one of these expressions to a glvalue that refers to the object designated by the operand, or to its complete object or a subobject thereof,
> - a conditional expression ([expr.cond]) that is a glvalue where the second or third operand is one of these expressions, or
> - a comma expression ([expr.comma]) that is a glvalue where the right operand is one of these expressions.

In the first case, the glvalue to which `r` is bound is obtained through a temporary materialization conversion from the prvalue `f1(A())`, so its lifetime is the same as `r`. In the second case, the glvalue to which `r` is bound is `f2(A())` (note `f2(A())` is an lvalue, so this time no temporary materialization conversion occurs), where none of the cases listed in the quoted paragraph applies, so its lifetime is not extended.

Note I use the word **normally** in the beginning of this answer. The cases listed in the above quoted paragraph, except the "temporary materialization conversion" case, are all exceptions.

Answer (score 2):

The temporary `A()` is bound to the parameter `a` in the function call. The lifetime extension is not transferred by passing it on to some other reference.

In the first case *another* temporary is created for the return value, as we can perhaps understand from the second destructor call.